# Python tornado async request handler

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I have written an async file upload RequestHandler. It is correct byte-wise, that is the files I receive are identical to the ones being sent. One issue that I am having trouble figuring out is upload delay. Specifically when I issue the post request to upload the file while testing locally I see the browser showing upload progress get stuck. For files close to 4MB in size it gets stuck on 50%+ for a little while then some time passes and it sends all of the data, and gets stuck on "waiting for localhost..." The whole process may last 3+ minutes.

The kicker is when I add print statements that end with a new line to data_received method the delays disappear. Does the print statement trigger the network buffers to be flushed somehow?

Here is the implementation of data_received, along with the helper methods:

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def _read_data(self, cont_buf):
    '''
    Read the file data.

    @param cont_buf - buffered HTTP request
    @param boolean indicating whether data is still being read and new
           buffer
    '''
    # Check only last characters of the buffer guaranteed to be large
    # enough to contain the boundary
    end_of_data_idx = cont_buf.find(self._boundary)

    if end_of_data_idx >= 0:
        data = cont_buf[:(end_of_data_idx - self.LSEP)]
        self.receive_data(self.header_list[-1], data)
        new_buffer = cont_buf[(end_of_data_idx + len(self._boundary)):]
        return False, new_buffer
    else:
        self.receive_data(self.header_list[-1], cont_buf)
        return True, b""

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def _parse_params(self, param_buf):
    '''
    Parse HTTP header parameters.

    @param param_buf - string buffer containing the parameters.
    @returns parameters dictionary
    '''
    params = dict()
    param_res = self.PAT_HEADERPARAMS.findall(param_buf)
    if param_res:
        for name, value in param_res:
            params[name] = value
    elif param_buf:
        params['value'] = param_buf
    return params

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def _parse_header(self, header_buf):
    '''
    Parses a buffer containing an individual header with parameters.

    @param header_buf - header buffer containing a single header
    @returns header dictionary
    '''
    res = self.PAT_HEADERVALUE.match(header_buf)
    header = dict()
    if res:
        name, value, tail = res.groups()
        header = {'name': name, 'value': value,
                  'params': (yield self._parse_params(tail))}
    elif header_buf:
        header = {"value": header_buf}
    return header

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def data_received(self, chunk):
    '''
    Processes a chunk of content body.

    @param chunk - a piece of content body.
    '''
    self._count += len(chunk)
    self._buffer += chunk
    # Has boundary been established?
    if not self._boundary:
        self._boundary, self._buffer =\
            (yield self._extract_boundary(self._buffer))

        if (not self._boundary
                and len(self._buffer) > self.BOUNDARY_SEARCH_BUF_SIZE):
            raise RuntimeError("Cannot find multipart delimiter.")

    while True:
        if self._receiving_data:
            self._receiving_data, self._buffer = yield self._read_data(self._buffer)
            if self._is_end_of_request(self._buffer):
                yield self.request_done()
                break
            elif self._is_end_of_data(self._buffer):
                break
        else:
            headers, self._buffer = yield self._read_headers(self._buffer)
            if headers:
                self.header_list.append(headers)
                self._receiving_data = True
            else:
                break
```

Comment: That's bizarre. I can't think of how it would make a difference, but where exactly in the method do you put the print statements? It might also help to see some of your helper methods like `_read_data()`.

Comment: I put the print statement at the very top. I'll include the helper methods in a few minutes.

Comment: This could be helpful to know, but I am running the server in a VirtualBox Ubuntu 14.04 with the port exposed to host environment.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have any ideas then. You could remove `@gen.coroutine` from most of your helper methods since they don't contain `yield`, but that shouldn't make a difference. Should `_read_data` use `yield` when it calls `receive_data`?

Comment: `receive_data` is not a coroutine, but an abstract method which should not be a coroutine. Regarding `@gen.coroutine` on most of my helper methods - I have them there to maximize interleaving. Is this not a good approach?

Comment: `@gen.coroutine` is effectively a noop if the function doesn't contain any `yields`

Comment: Does the noop nature still allow interleaving though? Btw, thank you for your help.

Comment: No, you have to yield something (could be `yield gen.moment`). But don't do this unless you see that you're blocking for a non-trivial amount of time, which doesn't look like the case here.